# Link to redirect to facebook messenger doesn't work on Mobile browser but works on Desktop Browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, redirect

I am trying to redirect from a web page to an m.me/?ref= facebook link which represents a Facebook Page. At the Desktop Browser, the redirection is working and opens the facebook messenger. When I am trying to do the same on the mobile browser, the redirection is done but the link doesn't open the facebook messenger in browser view or as an application.

Desktop browser: Chrome.

Mobile Browser: Samsung Internet, Chrome.

Tested ways to redirect:
window.location.href, window.open, window.location.replace

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is that it was blocked by the browser as a popup. I fixed this issue by putting the redirection to get triggered by a button. 
Redirect used: **window.open**